# Multiple softmax's along one dimension?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matrix

Suppose that I am adding multiple heads, with respectively (A, B, C) multiclass labels, over a latent vector, (H, 1), by left multiplying a matrix with a dimension of (A+B+C, H), and I obtain a matrix of (A+B+C, 1).

How can I apply three softmax's for A, B, and C respectively along the first dimension of the resulting matrix?

I implemented that by slicing the matrix but wonder if there are some elegant methods? In Numpy or Tensorflow(not high-level APIs)?